# An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found)

Tags: composer-php, symfony

Since yesterday I have this error in dev environment:

> An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found)

I don't understand why. I am using the lastest version of Symfony 3 and the symfony server.

**composer.json**

```
{
   ....
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.x-dev",
        "doctrine/mongodb": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.0",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0",
        "ismaambrosi/generator-bundle": "^2.5",
        "avanzu/admin-theme-bundle": "^1.3",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
        "jquery/jquery":  "1.11.*",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "^3.3",
        "stfalcon/tinymce-bundle": "2.0",
        "ancarebeca/full-calendar-bundle": "^3.0",
        "lemonway/php-sdk": "^1.4",
        "lemonway/sdk-bundle": "^1.1",
        "symfony/process": "^3.2",
        "vresh/twilio-bundle": "^1.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony": "^1.2",
        "symfony/validator": "^3.2",
        "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "^1.4"
    },
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find. 
I test the controller _wdt with the string parameter "empty". I show an error 500 beacuse of a mistake in service.yml file. I fix and it's work.

Thank you.